# What should the mail.debug=true option of javax.mail do?

Tags: java, log4j, jakarta-mail

In the configuration properties of my `javax.mail.Session` I have set `mail.debug=true`, but for some reason, this doesn't add any new output to the application log.

I've set the log4f logging level to ALL `log4j.rootLogger=ALL, stdout` and yet... nothing.

Is it possible that the javax.mail debug output is written somewhere else? Sounds unlikely, but nevertheless I thought it worth asking.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It goes on console. [Official FAQs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#debug)

Comment: How about an application running on Tomcat and logging to catalina.out?

Comment: Yes I believe so. Unless you have modified Tomcat to log its console output to a different file (or ignore it completely).

Comment: Apparently `mail.debug=true` isn't enough. In addition to that I had to set `session.setDebug(true);` which was suggested by the FAQ you linked me to.

Comment: Note that in mail version 1.4.1 @UsmanSaleem's info is no longer true. Session sets debug to true based on mail.debug property: if (Boolean.valueOf(props.getProperty("mail.debug")).booleanValue()) debug=true

Answer (score 10):

Setting log level of `com.sun.mail.smtp` to `DEBUG` worked on Wildfly(JBoss)

Comment: This worked like a charm after setting debug to true.

Answer (score 0):

Set sessionDebug variable to false. It will no longer print on the Tomcat console.

Comment: What does that mean?